# Can we use register interpolator twice on the same type

Tags: qt

In my window, I have on the one hand to grow a text inside a "button", and on the other to reduce an other one. (in two different animations, not in the same time)

To do this, I need to use `qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QFont>(myFontInterpolator)` twice.

But when I use the following code :

```
QVariant myFontInterpolator(const QFont &start, const QFont &end, qreal progress)
{
    if (progress<0.5)
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*25 + progress*30;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
    else
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*30 + progress*25;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
        Q_UNUSED(end)
}

MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    //some code
    qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QFont>(myFontInterpolator);
}
```

and

```
QVariant myFontInterpolator2(const QFont &start, const QFont &end, qreal progress)
{
    if (progress<0.5)
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*50 + progress*45;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
    else
    {
        int a = (1-progress)*45 + progress*50;
        QFont rt(start);
        rt.setPointSize(a);
        return rt;
    }
        Q_UNUSED(end)
}

MyTextOk::MyTextOk(QGraphicsObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(parent)
{
    // some code
    qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QFont>(myFontInterpolator2);
}
```

The call of `myFontInterpolator2` erase the call of `myFontInterpolator`, to the extent that both of my "changePolicySizeAnimation" are the same.

Is there a way to keep both or do I have to write one that works for the two ?

EDIT : This is my class MyVariantFont (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840124/can-we-use-register-interpolator-twice-on-the-same-type?noredirect=1#comment76663393_44840124))

```
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QFont>

class myVariantFont : public QPropertyAnimation
{
public:
    explicit myVariantFont();
    ~myVariantFont();

private :
    QVariant interpolated(const QVariant &start, const QVariant &end, qreal progress) const
    {
        if (progress<0.5)
        {
            int a = (1-progress)*25 + progress*30;
            QFont rt(start);
            rt.setPointSize(a);
            return rt;
        }
        else
        {
            int a = (1-progress)*30 + progress*25;
            QFont rt(start);
            rt.setPointSize(a);
            return rt;
        }
            Q_UNUSED(end)
    }
};
```

Comment: If you want to achieve this, you should subclass `QVariantAnimation` or `QPropertyAnimation` if you're dealing with properteis, and reimplement [`interpolated`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html#interpolated) method.

Comment: I can't subclass both QObject and QPropertyAnimation. I get the following error : 'QObject' is an ambiguous base of 'MyButton'/''MyTextOk'

Comment: What is the difference between creating a new class which subclass `QPropertyAnimation` and override `interpolated` and calling myFontInterpolator as I did ? I still can do it once ? (Once meaning every time the same animation)

Comment: You can set a flag which would determine how your interpolation will be calculated. Then you can use both.

Comment: I have trouble implementing this new class to my code. Do I have to call `qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QFont>(interpolated)` in my builder ? I have a bunch of errors doing this, including `no matching function to call 'qRegisterAnimationInterpolator(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'` and `variable 'QFont rt' has initializer but incomplete type`.

Comment: I added in my question my class. I can't write `QFont rt(<type = QVariant>start)`, does it means I have to change my definition of _interpolated_ ?

Comment: I'm sorry I have never subclassed `QPropertyAnimation before`. I have this message **QPropertyAnimation::updateState (): Changing state of an animation without target** when I click on my buttons. Si I added a `QObject *parent`, but it doesn't change anything. Do I have to override an other function ?

Comment: See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html#QPropertyAnimation-1) constructor of `QPropertyAnimation`. That is what you were using before. Make a constructor in your own class that takes those exact same parameters and call the base class constructor with those parameters.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed my builder as myVariantFont(QObject *target, const QByteArray &propertyName, QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) and it works. Now I have to define flags ?

Comment: You can use a `bool` or an `enum` to define how you will calculate your interpolation. Just check that in your `interpolated` method and use correct values accordingly.

Comment: Since I only have two choices, I decided to use a bool as an argument in my builder. Probably not the best idea, but it works. Thank you a lot @thuga

Comment: Feel free to post your working solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I sure will ! Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution if you have the same problem :

Creat a class which subclass `QPropertyAnimation` and override `interpolated`.
Use the same arguments in your builders as [QPropertyAnimation's](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html#QPropertyAnimation-1) and add one (enum or bool) which will allow you to do the right transformation.

When you call your animation, just call your new class instead of QPropertyAnimation, as follows :

```
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QFont>

class myVariantFont : public QPropertyAnimation
{
public:
    explicit myVariantFont(QObject *target, const QByteArray &propertyName, bool choose)
    {
        choice = choose;
    }

    ~myVariantFont();

private :
    QVariant interpolated(const QVariant &start, const QVariant &end, qreal progress) const
    {
        if (choice == false)
        {
            if (progress<0.5)
            {
                int a = (1-progress)*25 + progress*30;
                QFont rt(start.value<QFont>());
                rt.setPointSize(a);
                return rt;
            }
            else
            {
                int a = (1-progress)*30 + progress*25;
                QFont rt(start.value<QFont>());
                rt.setPointSize(a);
                return rt;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (progress<0.5)
            {
                int a = (1-progress)*50 + progress*45;
                QFont rt(start.value<QFont>());
                rt.setPointSize(a);
                return rt;
            }
            else
            {
                int a = (1-progress)*45 + progress*50;
                QFont rt(start.value<QFont>());
                rt.setPointSize(a);
                return rt;
            }
        }
            Q_UNUSED(end)
    }

protected :
    bool choice;
};
```

and

```
myVariantFont *animation = new myVariantFont(textOk,"font", true);

animation->setDuration(300);
animation->setStartValue(QFont("Colibri",50));
animation->setEndValue(QFont("Colibri",50));

animation->start();
```